# Problema ao puxar lista do servidor no Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Opa galera, estou puxando uma lista do servidor e populando um `RecyclerView` com essa lista. Porém quando a lista estiver vazia, quero que apareça uma mensagem do tipo: "Ainda não existem itens cadastrados para esse produto". Mas não um `Toast`, e sim uma mensagem fixa num `TextView`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Valeu

```
public class ProductAdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String APP_NAME = "PanApp";
public static final String URL = "https://panapp-backend.appspot.com/_ah/api";
private RecyclerView rvProductAdmin;
private Button btnNewProduct;
private Long bakeryId;
private Bundle params;
private TextView txtAnswer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_product_admin, frameLayout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_admin);
    setTitle("Meus Produtos");

    Intent it = getIntent();
    params = it.getExtras();
    if (params != null) {
        bakeryId = params.getLong("bakeryId");
    }

    txtAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAnswer);
    rvProductAdmin = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.product_list_admin);
    btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new_product);
    btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            params.putLong("bakeryId", bakeryId);
            Intent intentFormProduct = new Intent(ProductAdminActivity.this, FormProductActivity.class);
            intentFormProduct.putExtras(params);
            startActivity(intentFormProduct);
        }
    });
    new ProductListAsyncTask(this).execute();
}

private class ProductListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CollectionResponseProduct> {
    ProductAdminActivity context;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public ProductListAsyncTask(ProductAdminActivity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Listando Produtos...");
        pd.show();
    }

    protected CollectionResponseProduct doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        CollectionResponseProduct collectionResponseProduct = null;
        try {
            ProductApi.Builder builder = new ProductApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null).setRootUrl(URL);
            builder.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
            ProductApi service =  builder.build();
            collectionResponseProduct = service.list().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Erro", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return collectionResponseProduct;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    protected void onPostExecute(CollectionResponseProduct collectionResponseProduct) {
        pd.dismiss();
        if(collectionResponseProduct.size() > 0){
            List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Product> _list = collectionResponseProduct.getItems();
            for (Product productAux : _list) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProductName(productAux.getProductName());
                product.setProductPrice(productAux.getProductPrice());
                product.setType(productAux.getType());
                product.setBakeryId(productAux.getBakeryId());
                product.setProductImage(productAux.getProductImage());
                if(Objects.equals(bakeryId, product.getBakeryId())){
                    list.add(product);
                }
            }
            rvProductAdmin.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProductAdminActivity.this));
            rvProductAdmin.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(list));
        } else {
            txtAnswer.setText("Não existem produtos cadastrados!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder> {

private final List<Product> products;

public ProductAdapter(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_product, viewGroup, false);
    //final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product, viewGroup, false);
    return new ProductViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder productViewHolder, int i) {
    productViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(products.get(i).getProductName());
    productViewHolder.tvPrice.setText(products.get(i).getProductPrice().toString());
    productViewHolder.tvCategory.setText(products.get(i).getType());
    //productViewHolder.tvItensSale.setText(products.get(i).getItensSale());

    String strBase64 = products.get(i).getProductImage();
    byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

    productViewHolder.ivProduct.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}
}
```

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.gregmachado.panapp, PID: 8730
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.gregmachado.panapp.activity.ProductAdminActivity$ProductListAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProductAdminActivity.java:106)
                                                                      at com.gregmachado.panapp.activity.ProductAdminActivity$ProductListAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProductAdminActivity.java:70)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Se você colocar seu código aqui, eu te ajudarei!

Comment: Coloquei o código, aquele Toast ali não tá funcionando, não sei se tem a ver com o ColletionResponse, primeira vez que trabalho com esse tipo de lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai fazer o seguinte, na sua `activity_product_admin.xml` crie um TextView

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResposta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resposta"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
       />
```

Na sua classe `ProductAdminActivity` você vai instanciar seu `TextView`, primeiro declarando uma variável do tipo `TextView` e depois fazer a ligação com o `.xml`.

```
private TextView textReposta;
```

Dentro do seu `onCreate` você faz desta forma:

```
textResposta= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResposta);
```

Aí resta somente substitui seu `Toast` por o seguinte código:

```
textResposta.setText("Não existem produtos cadastrados!");
```

Só isso! Abraços! Boa Sorte!

Comment: ai esta. Também achei que era só isso, mas dispara um Exception. Editei lá e coloquei.

Comment: @GrégoriMachado ajuda ai irmão. Qndo você comentar, já atualiza seu código ou coloque ai senão fica difícil saber o que você está errando.

Comment: respondi e fui atualizar o código.

Comment: @GrégoriMachado tá atualizado não.

Comment: Ué, coloquei o exception no fim do código.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: De qualquer forma. Pensei aqui e fiz várias tentativas. Consegui resolver. Vou postar a solução.

Comment: @GrégoriMachado brother, é pra atualizar seu código com as alterações que eu inseri.

Comment: Atualizei também agora

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
protected CollectionResponseProduct doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        CollectionResponseProduct collectionResponseProduct = null;
        ProductApi.Builder builder = new ProductApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null).setRootUrl(URL);
        builder.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
        ProductApi service =  builder.build();
        try {
            collectionResponseProduct = service.list().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Erro", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return collectionResponseProduct;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    protected void onPostExecute(CollectionResponseProduct collectionResponseProduct) {
        pd.dismiss();
        List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Product> _list = collectionResponseProduct.getItems(); // fiz o get pro List antes
        if(_list == null){ // e fiz o teste aqui no List ao invés do Collection Response
            txtAnswer.setText("Não existem produtos cadastrados!");
        } else {
            for (Product productAux : _list) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProductName(productAux.getProductName());
                product.setProductPrice(productAux.getProductPrice());
                product.setType(productAux.getType());
                product.setBakeryId(productAux.getBakeryId());
                product.setProductImage(productAux.getProductImage());
                if(Objects.equals(bakeryId, product.getBakeryId())){
                    list.add(product);
                }
            }
            rvProductAdmin.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ProductAdminActivity.this));
            rvProductAdmin.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(list));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você sabe que não ganha nenhum mérito respondendo sua própria pergunta né?! É muito melhor você dar os créditos para quem te ajuda, porque você acaba ganhando também com isso. Abraços

Comment: cara não me leva a mal. Eu não to nem ai pros créditos. Ao contrário de você. Desde o primeiro comentário você respondeu com o ar de superioridade. Tudo que tu disse pra eu fazer, eu já tinha feito.
Se eu soubesse tudo de programação não estaria pedindo ajuda. Mas creio que não exista alguém que saiba tudo de programação né.

E se o problema é crédito, eu marco a tua resposta como solução.

Comment: De boa! Cada um tem seu pensamento e eu respeito o seu! Abraços